# Identify numeric rows in variable mostly composed by non-numeric rows

Tags: r, subset, numeric

I have a data frame `df` with a variable `Var.1` composed mostly by string variables as follows

```
 Var.1
 RA305
 RA430
 RA773
 RA7CQ
 RA90J
 .....
```

Yet, this variable may also contain factors that are composed by a sole number (e.g. all characters are digits). I want to create a new data frame by subsetting the latter observations and I wonder how I can identify them. My attempt has been

```
new_df = filter(df, !grepl("[:digit:]", Var.1))
```

But still I cannot obtain the observations that are numeric only. Any suggestions?

Comment: TRy `filter(df, grepl("^-?[0-9.]+$", Var.1))`

Comment: Maybe also mention all the dependencies too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `^` and `$` to specify the start and end of the string in `grepl`.  As we are only `filter`ing the numeric only rows, it should contains only numbers

```
filter(df, grepl("^[0-9]+$", Var.1))
```

In the OP's method, `[[:digit:]]+` is lacking an outer `[]`.  Also, it is non-specific as it can select elements that can be either all numbers, numbers with characters etc.  So, by negating that, we may get elements with non-numeric elements (just the opposite of what we are aiming for - assuming there are those cases in the dataset)

Comment: @Spacedman  Thanks, you are right.  I didn't think about that.

Comment: It works. Many thanks for the suggestion and the explanation, @akrun.